# Creating joins based on range of number value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Could you guys provide me on the situation below?
I have 2 tables.

Table 1 looks like this:
[image]

Meanwhile, this is table 2:

[image]

I would like to join table 2 to table 1 to lookup the grade for each job based on the upper and lower limit column.

By conceptualizing some of the lovely answers here, I manage to come up with a statement that looks something like this:

```
FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table2.[score] >= table1.[lower limit]) AND (table2.[score] <= table1.[upper limit])
```

The statement above manage to join them according to a range, however, for some unknown reasons, some rows from the left table went missing and I could not determine what it is. e.g (2000 rows in table 2, but only 1800 in the query)

I am sure the join is the cause, as if i change the join to a equal left join, 2000 rows appear in the query.

Can someone advice me on this?

Regards,
Guang Yong

Comment: Do you have fractional scores that fall between the grades - ie between 59 and 60?  Or blank grades, grades <0 or >100?  I think your join may exclude these scores - although I would expect a left join to force all the records into the result.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be much cleaner to create a table with values from 1-100 and assign them each on of your categories, and essentially mirroring your table 1.
Then you can do Table 2

```
SELECT Table1.Grade, Table2.Score
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Score = Table1.Score
```

This would definitely cover all integers between 0 and 100.

If you are manually inputing the scores, you could also use a data macro as simple as this:
go to Table Tools >> Table >> Before Change

Then use the **Set Field** Action, and set

**Name** = `Table2.Grade`

**Value** = `IIf([Score]>=70,"Good",IIf([Score]<=59,"bad","so so"))`

With this ^ everytime you type in a score, it will automatically populate the grade column.

Another option is create a query as follows, that will evaluate each line and assign the proper grade:

```
SELECT Table2.Score, 
IIf([Score]>=70,"Good",IIf([Score]<=59,"bad","so so")) AS Grade
FROM Table2;
```

Good luck!